# why is the dimension of $U \oplus V$ = dimension of (U+V) iff $U \cap V = \{0\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

$U,V$ are finite vector spaces. This makes intuitive sense to me, like in the case of the $x$-axis as $U$ and $yz$-axis as $V$ in $R^3$, but I don't know how to prove it/why it works in general. However, I think that $\operatorname{dim}(U+V) = \dim(U) + \dim (V) + \dim(U \cap V)$ is relevant.

Comment: The correct identity is $\dim(U + V) = \dim(U) + \dim(V) -\dim(U \cap V)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Using the equation you wrote relating the dimensions of $U,V$ and $U+V$ you can deduce that $\dim(U+V)=\dim(U)+\dim(V)$ if and only if $\dim(U\cap V)=0$.

Comment: I got that part, but I don't know how to show that dim(U+V) = dim($U \oplus V$)

Comment: @user64171 $\dim(U\oplus V)=\dim(U)+\dim(V)$!

Comment: Oh, I see how that follows using the number of elements in the bases of U and V, and the definition of direct product. Thank you!